# ngFor not displaying array data

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a component that is being passed in a number of objects through an input.

```
<rooms-component [rooms]="Rooms$ | async"></rooms-component>
```

In the child component, I am putting all the objects inside an array in OnChanges

```
ngOnChanges() {
        this.rmArray= Array(this.rooms);
    }
```

And in the HTML I have a ngFor to display the data

```
    <li *ngFor="let room of rmArray">
        {{ room.name }}
    </li>
```

This does not display anything. I suspect it has something to do with how I am creating the array. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: is there any reason of using ngOnChanges() instead of ngOnInit() ?

Comment: There isn't. I was just testing it with ngOnChanges. I tried ngOnInit as well and same result.

Comment: try this `ngOnChanges() {
        this.rmArray= Array(this.rooms); 
        console.log('this.rooms',this.rooms);
    }` does this print any result ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, pretty much everything is wrong here.

First of all you can link the input `rmArray` straight to your template.

Secondly, if for some reason you want to do some kind of transformation to the data, the best practice is to do it via a setter on the input.

```
@Input()
set rmArray(value) {
  this.transformedData = PLACE YOUR LOGIC HERE
}

transformedData: any[];
```

Lastly, you need immutable actions.

`this.rmArray= Array(this.rooms)`

should be:

`this.rmArray= new Array(this.rooms)` or `this.rmArray= [...this.rooms]`

Keep in mind that `ngOnChanges` is used when you want to combine data from multiple inputs

Answer (score 0):

You can send rooms$ to rooms-component instead of (rooms$ | async). I mean something like this:

```
<room-component [rooms$]=rooms$></room-component>
```

Then you van use "async" in rooms-component to receive room in ngFor. like this:

```
<li *ngFor="let room of (rooms$ |async) ">
    {{ room.name }}
</li>
```

This way, you do not need to use ngOnChanges()  to update rooms list in rooms-component.

I create a small project to show how it works:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e4uefw?file=src/app/app.component.ts